# How to configure Git in Debian to use Nano or Vim by default?

Tags: linux, git, vim, debian, nano

I want to start using [Vi(m)](https://www.ccsf.edu/Pub/Fac/vi.html) to edit documents, and one use case for me is to make my commits with `vi` to start learning their commands. **Debian** comes with both `nano` and `vi` installed but when I make a commit the one that opens is `nano`.

I know how to open a file in `vi`:

```sh
vi -v someFile.ext
vi -y some_other_file.ext2
```

What I want is to make vi (or any other editor) default when committing with git.

*Is there a flag or something that makes me open `vi` when making a commit by default?*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+set+%5Bvim%5D+default+editor

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42727/281844 to change default editor on Debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Hi Israel, go to the `.gitconfig` and change the editor from nano to vi. if there is no editor specified, add an editor to the core section.

```
  [core]
    excludesfile = -/.gitignore_global
    editor = vi
```